# How to use `strtoul` to parse string where zero may be valid?

Tags: c, string-parsing, strtoul

According to the documentation for `strtoul`, regarding its return value...

> This function returns the converted integral number as a long int value. If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned.

What if I'm parsing a user-supplied string of "0" where, for my application, "0" may be a valid entry?  In that case it seems that I have no way to determine from using `strtoul` if a valid conversion was performed.  Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: You could check `endptr` if it points to the begining?

Comment: There might be other invalid strings, such as `asd123`. You may also check if the first character of the string is a digit or no (if the string is not empty). All in all, Sourav Ghosh's answer seems more extensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to use `strtoul` to parse string where zero may be valid?

Any value returned from  `strtoul()` may be from an expected string input or from *other* not so expected strings.  Further tests are useful.

The following *strings* all return 0 from `strtoul()`

- OK `"0"`, `"-0"`, `"+0"`
- Not OK `""`, `"abc"`
- Usually considered OK:  `" 0"`
- OK or not OK depending on goals:  `"0xyz"`, `"0 "`, `"0.0"`

`strtoul()` has the various detection modes.

```
int base = 10;
char *endptr;  //  Store the location where conversion stopped

errno = 0;
unsigned long y = strtoul(s, &endptr, base);

if (s == endptr) puts("No conversion");      // "", "abc"
else if (errno == ERANGE) puts("Overflow");
else if (*endptr) puts("Extra text after the number"); // "0xyz", "0 ", "0.0"
else puts("Mostly successful");
```

What is not yet detected.

- Negative input.  `strtoul()` effectively wraps around such that `strtoul("-1", 0, 10) == ULONG_MAX)`.  **This issue is often missed in cursory documentation review.**
- Leading white space allowed.  This may or may not be desired.

---

To also detect negative values:

```
// find sign
while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) {
  s++;
}
char sign = *s;

int base = 10;
char *endptr;  //  Store the location where conversion stopped
errno = 0;
unsigned long y = strtoul(s, &endptr, base);

if (s == endptr) puts("No conversiosn");
else if (errno == ERANGE) puts("Overflow");
else if (*endptr) puts("Extra text after the number"); 
else if (sign == '-' && y != 0) puts("Negative value"); 
else puts("Successful");
```

Answer (score 9):

Read further the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul):

> Since `strtoul()` can legitimately return `0` or `ULONG_MAX` (`ULLONG_MAX` for `strtoull()`) on both success and failure, the calling program should set `errno` to `0` before the call, and then determine if an error occurred by checking whether `errno` has a nonzero value after the call.

Also, to handle another scenario, where no digits were read in the input. If this happens, `strtol()` sets the value of `*endptr` to that of the `nptr`. So, you should also check that the pointer values compare equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to pass the address of a `char` pointer and check if it is pointing to the beginning of the string:

```
char *str = "0";
char *endptr;
unsgined long x = strtoul(str, &endptr, 10);

if(endptr == str)
{
    //Nothing was read
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
/* SPDX-Identifier: CC0-1.0 */

const char *parse_ulong(const char *src, unsigned long *to)
{
    const char    *end;
    unsigned long  val;

    if (!src) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    end = src;
    errno = 0;
    val = strtoul(src, (char **)(&end), 0);
    if (errno)
        return NULL;
    if (end == src) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (to)
       *to = val;

    return end;
}
```

This function parses the unsigned long in the string `src`, returning a pointer to the first unparsed character in `src`, with the unsigned long saved to `*to`.  If there is an error, the function will return NULL with errno set to indicate the error.

If you compare the function to [`man 3 strtoul`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html), you'll see it handles all error cases correctly, and only returns non-NULL when `src` yields a valid unsigned long. Especially see the Notes section. Also pay attention to how negative numbers are handled.

This same pattern works for `strtol()`, `strtod()`, `strtoull()`.